# How do I change the color of edited tasks in JavaScript based on the type of text?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, the code is not functioning correctly. If the text is altered to only the word 'Grocery', the text doesn't turn blue. Any edit turns the task background pink. How can I add more variety to this function, i.e. if the text includes the word Grocery, or Milk, among other words, it will edit to blue. Or if the text only has the word Grocery, or Milk, it will turn blue. Or any other color changes that could be made by editing the task.

```
//dynamic colour edit task
function change(){
var text=document.getElementById("div").innerHTML;
if(text=="A"){
    document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor=("blue");
    }
else{
document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor=("pink");};
/*can add similar code*/

};
```

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Please make it clear what you really want

Comment: instead of using `text=={...}`, try to use regular expression, it should be clearer, and cover all the cases you need

Answer (score 1):

If you add all your blue items in an array, you could just use indexOf to check if the text is in the array.

```js
function change() {
  var blueItems = ["Grocery", "Milk", "Water"];
  var text = document.getElementById("div").innerHTML;
  if (blueItems.indexOf(text) !== -1) {
    document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor = ("blue");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor = ("pink");
  };
  /*can add similar code*/
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

Have a style with classes

```
.blue  { color: blue }
.pink  { color: pink }
```

and use

```js
//dynamic colour edit task
const shopping = ["Milk","Grocery"]

function change() {
  const div = document.getElementById('div');
  const text = document.getElementById("div").textContent;
  const found = shopping.includes(text);
  div.classList.toggle("blue",found);
  div.classList.toggle("pink",!found);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set all your keywords in the array. Check value from the array if `div` text matches the content using a loop.

```js
var keys = ["Milk", "Grocery"]
change(keys);

function change(keys) {
  keys.some(function(value, index, _arr) {
    var text = document.getElementById("div").innerHTML;

    if (text.indexOf(value) > -1) {
      document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor = ("blue");
      return value === value;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor = ("pink");
    };
    /*can add similar code*/

  });

};
```

```html
<div id='div'>Milk</div>
```

<sub>Note:</sub>

1. change `div` content to see different color apply on div.
2. Use `toLowerCase()` for case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the question is asking but if you are looking to change the background of something based off the word, I would start by using an array of the words you want to check against to change the color. If that word is found in the array then change the styles. I believe the array.find() method would work for your case but I am attaching the javascript arrays cheat sheet for you too https://dev.to/vincenius/javascript-array-functions-cheatsheet-1c15

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.